# Immediately Called Functions are 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var catCreyz = function() { console.log('maaaow'); }.call()
```

and when I test its type:

```
typeof catCreyz
```

The result returned is:

> undefined

Why?

Comment: It's because the .call() bit executes the function and returns the result, which is undefined in this case.

Comment: Why do you think it would be `function`?

Comment: Because 'call' returns no result?

Comment: The order of operations is like so:

var catCreyz = ((function() { console.log('maaaow'); }).call())

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, yeah- I had a bit of a brain fart. Sorry to trouble you coolcats!

Comment: @furydevoid What are you saying ? This would still return `undefined` ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Lets break it down. First, an anonymous function is created. This anonymous function is not assigned to anything; rather it is immediately invoked with call. The function returns undefined, which is assigned to the var. This all happens on the same line, which is where the confusion lies.

Comment: @furydevoid Yeah I agree :) I thought you mean that what you wrote would return `function` :) Sorry I got confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) returns what the function being called returns.  Your function returns nothing

```
var catCreyz = function() { console.log('maaaow'); }.call()
//logs undefined
console.log(catCreyz);

var result = function() { return "foo"; }.call()
//logs foo
console.log(result);

var myFunc = function() { console.log('maaaow'); }
//logs the function
console.log(myFunc);
```

Comment: I think he wanted `catCreyz` to store the function being called

Answer (score 1):

Call executes the function, and you're missing a return statement in your function, Javascript does not return the last expression like other languages. You must explicitly return a value, else you get undefined.

If you want an instance of catCreyz, then take the call() off the expression.